# Need Help in Kotlin Android - fragments

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to get session id to menu fragment. but it doesn't work. In this I get Session ID from Login Activity. Now I need to get that id to Menu fragment. In this one activity loaded five Fragments. I used bundle for load data.
Here's my activity.kt

```
class Home : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val HomeFragment = HomeFragment()
    private val CreditsFragment = CreditsFragment()
    private val BusFragment = BusFragment()
    private val NotificationsFragment = NotificationsFragment()
    private val MenuFragment = MenuFragment()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.home)

         val sessionId = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID")
        textView4.setText(sessionId)

        replaceFragment(HomeFragment)

        bottomNavBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
            when (it.itemId){
                R.id.menu_home -> replaceFragment(HomeFragment)
                R.id.menu_credits -> replaceFragment(CreditsFragment)
                R.id.menu_bus -> replaceFragment(BusFragment)
                R.id.menu_notification -> replaceFragment(NotificationsFragment)
                R.id.menu_menu -> replaceFragment(MenuFragment)
            }
            true
        }

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId)
        val myObj = MenuFragment()
        myObj.setArguments(bundle)
    }


    private fun replaceFragment (fragment:Fragment){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }



}
```

here's my updated menu fragment.kt. I think I have problem in this. can u plzzz help me to find it.

```
class MenuFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        arguments?.let {
            var sessionId = it.toString()
            emailAddressText.setText(sessionId)

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false)

    }

    companion object {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change activity to this :

```
    val bundle = Bundle()  
    bundle.putString("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId)
    MenuFragment.setArguments(bundle)
    bottomNavBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
        when (it.itemId){
            R.id.menu_home -> replaceFragment(HomeFragment)
            R.id.menu_credits -> replaceFragment(CreditsFragment)
            R.id.menu_bus -> replaceFragment(BusFragment)
            R.id.menu_notification -> replaceFragment(NotificationsFragment)
            R.id.menu_menu -> replaceFragment(MenuFragment)
        }
        true
    }
```

in the fragment you also need to use `arguments.getString("EXTRA_SESSION_ID")` to retreive sessionId value. and place `emailAddressText.setText(sessionId)`
in onViewCreated method because in `onCreate()` method views are not ready yet.
so change the fragment like this :

```
  class MenuFragment : Fragment() {
  var sessionId = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        sessionId = it.getString("EXTRA_SESSION_ID","")
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    emailAddressText.setText(sessionId)
  }
 }
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I think in menufragment.kt  have some problems

Comment: I attached my updated my menu fragment.kt

Comment: @ABI I have updated the code, check if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The `MenuFragment` instance you have in your `replaceFragment` transaction is different from the one where you set the sessionid argument to.

Remove the other instantiation `val myObj = MenuFragment()` and set arguments on `MenuFragment` instead.

(Naming convention hint: it's easier to keep types and objects apart if types are CamelCase and types lowerCamelCase. For example, `private val menuFragment = MenuFragment()`.)

Comment: yaa I try it but it doesn't work for me

Comment: I attached my updated my menu fragment.kt.